# VsCode works only with npm run dev

Tags: debugging, npm, visual-studio-code

[image]I have a laravel project with vue in Visual Studio Code, the problem is that all the changes are not saved (therefore they are not seen) ... it only works when I do **npm run dev**, when compiling everything its when I can see the new changes but, The idea would not be this, but to make a change and see it live (debbugin).

In the pic you can see what i mean....
the code (black square) says "Visita" so:
1- i save the file
2- go to the browser to see the text/button/change

3- you can see in the green square the diference (i cant see the change, thats the problem)